# Ignoring the Http Request Defaults in jMeter

Tags: jmeter

Is there a way to tell an HTTP Request in jMeter to ignore the HTTP Request Defaults element?  I've got a string of about 100 HTTP Requests that need the defaults but the last few I need to keep them from posting what's in the defaults.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[HTTP Request Defaults](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request_Defaults) controls defaults when you don't define the field in the HTTP Request.

So just fill in in the particular [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) the fields you want to override and you're done.

Comment: For anyone looking at this in the future, if you want to override the port to nothing, you have to put a space, or else it will use the port number from the request manager.